# make element dragable in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to make some draggable element in yii2 advance application. In PHP or simply HTML example just like http://jqueryui.com/draggable. I try in Yii2 but it didn't work. Can someone help me please?
this is the view page code.

```
 <?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'Generate Table';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-generateTable">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Test for drag and drop function</p>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
    </div>
<style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
```

and the application asset is something like this

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{


public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'

    ];
    public $js = [  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'      ,
        'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js',

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Sorry my english is not quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to add jQuery and jQueryUi libraries again, it's already available in Yii2. You need to change your `AppAsset` to something like below.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        '...'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Note: You need to make sure that your `AppAsset` is registered in your main layout file and any errors in the console as well.

In your view file use `$this->registerJs()` and `$this->registerCss()` to add custom CSS and JS codes to avoid conflicts. The view file could be something like this below.

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'Generate Table';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-generateTable">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Test for drag and drop function</p>

    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
       <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$css = <<< CSS
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
CSS;
$js = <<< JS
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
JS;
$this->registerCss($css);
$this->registerJs($js);
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem. If you want to change the version of the jQuery and jQuery libraries you may have a look at the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Comment: thank you. it works.Note: actually, I don't have to add 'yii\jui\JuiAsset',again after install Jquery-UI. But it also work when I add 'yii\jui\JuiAsset'.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps you. I think better you use`yii\jui\JuiAsset`instead of manually added to the asset.

Comment: yeah. I've add it. :D